# Cannot figure out how to parse xml array into object entity

Tags: xml, spring-boot

I am currently working on parsing XML to Java Object.

However, There is one little thing I can never figure out.

XML below cannot be parsed by my code.

Hope someone can see and tell what's the problem.

```
<KeepAlive>
  <ActiveEvent>5906526</ActiveEvent>
  <ActiveEvent>5911113</ActiveEvent>
  <ProviderId>71</ProviderId>
</KeepAlive>
```

code is as below

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "ACTIVE_EVENT")
public class ActiveEvent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE_EVENT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "INSERTED_ACTIVE_EVENT_ID")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="ActiveEvent")
    @JacksonXmlText
    private Long activeEventId;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Dummy1", isAttribute = true)
    private Integer dummy1;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Dummy2")
    private Integer dummy2;

    @Column(name = "FOREIGN_KEEPALIVE_ID")
    private Long keepAliveId;

    @Column(name = "STAMP")
    private Long stamp;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        stamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        stamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    }

}
```

and the super class "KeepAlive" gets the "ActiveEvent" array as below.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "FOREIGN_KEEPALIVE_ID")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="ActiveEvent")
private List<ActiveEvent> activeEvents = new ArrayList<>();
```

Hope some wise man can help me out.

FYI below error keep pops up.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.ibin.domain.message.ActiveEvent` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('5906526')
```

Comment: and the error you are getting is?

Comment: @Thomas Andolf edited the post.

Comment: As the error says, there is no constructor in the class that can take in a string